# ASP.Net GridView EmptyDataTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView that gets updated by a DropDownList value. Using EmptyDataTemplate, it displays a message that basically says no value is available for the select state. The issue I am running into is, when I first go to the page that message gets pops cause the dropdownlist value is empty, is there away that I can prevent this? I want EmptyDataTemplate to be hidden until a user selects a value from the DropDownList.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you hide the gridview until a value is chosen initially?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: The answer by mreyeros worked, thank you for asking. All I did was creating a selectedIndexChange and set the GridView visibility to true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hide the entire grid and in your selectedIndexChanged event of the dropdownlist bind the grid and set its visibility so that it is displayed.